# Hybrid MPI+OpenMP Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp, hybrid

I am retrofitting OpenMP to an MPI Fortran computational fluid dynamics code.

I am using the thread funneled approach.

As of now, everytime I run tests the MPI+OpenMP code runs slower (I am using more processor for the MPI+OpenMP version, and it still runs slower, I compared for example 2 CPUs with 2 MPI processes and 6 CPUs with 2 MPI processes and 3 OpenMP threads.

I have been using gprof and I noticed that functions that live in the serial part of the code take thousands of times longer time when I enable OpenMP. Anyone knows why this would happen?

--- edit on 15th September 2016 --

Thank you everyone for the input.

Meanwhile I profiled my code with TAU and understood that gprof was attributing the idle time of threads to a random function. On TAU this same idle time is attributed to the ".TAU aplication". My current problem I seeing a marginal speed up (less than 5%) when I add threads.

@Zulan : Meanwhile I profiled my code with TAU by requesting more threads+processes (2MPI x 7 threads) than I have CPUs available (dual thread quadcore), and by doing this I can see the OpenMP barrier taking a very big time in the execution, so I do not believe this is the case.

@VladimirF I understand your point, sorry for not clearing it out, but I am comparing 2 MPI processes with 1 thread each vs. 2 MPI processes with 2 threads each, so I am actually doubling the resources and seeing no speedup

@tim18 I have not checked using a debugger, but I have checked my output and the results are correct to machine precision

Here is a specific loop that the code executes.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO  & ! Has masque, so should be dynamic
!$OMP& private (k,fa3, j, jp, fa2) &
!$OMP& shared (z3r,z4r,z2r,cur,cvr,cwr) &
!$OMP& schedule (runtime)
DO i=1, nL1     ! loop 1
   DO k=1,nG3     ! loop 2
      fa3=fac3(k)
      DO j=1,nG2,2   ! loop 3a
         IF(masque(j,k))THEN
            jp=j+1   
            fa2=fac2(j)   
            !
            uu(j,k,i) = fa3*cvr(jp,k,i)-fa2*cwr(jp,k,i)
            uu(jp,k,i)=-fa3*cvr(j,k,i) +fa2*cwr(j,k,i)

            vv(j,k,i) =-fa3*cur(jp,k,i)-vv(j,k,i)
            vv(jp,k,i)= fa3*cur(j,k,i) -vv(jp,k,i)

            ww(j,k,i) =ww(j,k,i)  +fa2*cur(jp,k,i)
            ww(jp,k,i)=ww(jp,k,i) -fa2*cur(j,k,i)
         ENDIF
      ENDDO     ! loop 3a

      DO j=1,nG2  ! loop 3b
        IF(masque(j,k))THEN
          z3r(j,k,i) = cur(j,k,i)
          z4r(j,k,i) = cvr(j,k,i)
          z2r(j,k,i) = cwr(j,k,i)
        ENDIF
      ENDDO     ! loop 3b
   ENDDO   ! loop 2
ENDDO   ! loop 1
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

The results with TAU are the following:

```
%Time    Exclusive    Inclusive       #Call      #Subrs  Inclusive Name
              msec   total msec                          usec/call 


2 MPI + 2 threads --- 

MEAN
  0.9        0.265        8,943          39          39     229330 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8        0.106       17,887          78          78     229324 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8       17,805       17,887          78          78     229323 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0           82           82          78           0       1052 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0          328          328         312           0       1052 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]


TOTAL 
  0.9            1       35,775         156         156     229330 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8        0.423     1:11.549         312         312     229324 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8     1:11.220     1:11.548         312         312     229323 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]

Node 0 Thread 0 
  1.8        0.547       17,919          78          78     229737 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8        0.128       17,918          78          78     229730 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8       17,863       17,918          78          78     229729 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0           55           55          78           0        714 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
Node 0 Thread 1 
  1.8        0.116       17,919          78          78     229732 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8       17,788       17,918          78          78     229730 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0          130          130          78           0       1667 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]

Node 1 Thread 0 
  1.8        0.511       17,856          78          78     228923 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8        0.087       17,855          78          78     228917 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8       17,788       17,918          78          78     229730 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0           40           40          78           0        523 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
Node 1 Thread 1 
  1.8        0.092       17,855          78          78     228917 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.8       17,753       17,855          78          78     228916 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0          101          101          78           0       1302 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/runxxx/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]


2 MPI + 1 thread ---

Node 0 Thread 0 
  2.0        0.273       20,345          78          78     260834 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  2.0        0.101       20,344          78          78     260831 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  2.0       20,344       20,344          78          78     260829 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0        0.184        0.184          78           0          2 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]

Node 0 Thread 1 
  1.9        0.261       20,113          78          78     257860 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9        0.072       20,112          78          78     257856 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9       20,112       20,112          78          78     257855 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0        0.176        0.176          78           0          2 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]

MEAN
  1.9        0.267       20,229          78          78     259347 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9       0.0865       20,228          78          78     259344 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9       20,228       20,228          78          78     259342 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0         0.18         0.18          78           0          2 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]


TOTAL
  1.9        0.534       40,458         156         156     259347 paralleldo (parallel fork/join) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9        0.173       40,457         156         156     259344 paralleldo (parallel begin/end) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  1.9       40,457       40,457         156         156     259342 paralleldo (loop body) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
  0.0         0.36         0.36         156           0          2 paralleldo (barrier enter/exit) [OpenMP location: file:/home/pedroea/Desktop/2MPI1OpenMP_omplib/m_solvvel.f90 <517, 551>]
```

There is a marginal speedup, but it does not come even close to being 50%, and the problem is not the overheads.

Comment: Maybe you are somehow running multiple threads on a single core. A specific answer to your question is impossible unless you provide more information about your code, your system, MPI implementation, settings, batch system, actual performance measurement results, ....

Comment: This lack of improvement of MPI+threads versus pure MPI is a common problem which has been asked here several times before.  There is no reason why hybrid MPI-OpenMP would make a simple code faster, it actually brings a lot of new stuff which makes it slower. It is normal and expected. If there is any performance gain, it will be for many computer nodes, not for small clusters or single computers.

Comment: If anything gets thousand times slower you probably has a bug. We cannot help you with findings bugs in your code if you don't show the code.

Comment: Recent MPI implementations include facilities to pin the threads of each MPI rank appropriately on the same segment of your memory system (almost certainly not splitting a core among ranks).  You do need to verify your OpenMP on 1 rank and eliminate race conditions.

Comment: Also read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I edited the question with more data.